# realm react-native: how to query correctly an array of strings

Tags: react-native, realm

can someone show me how to query an array of strings with realm in react-native?

assume i have an array like the following:

```
const preferences = ["automatic","suv","blue",eco]
```

What I want is to get realm results where ALL strings in the attribute "specifications" of Cars is in "preferences".

E.g.: If an instance of Cars.specifications contains ["automatic","suv"]
a result should be returned.

But if an instance of Cars.specifications contained ["automatic,"suv","green"] this instance shouldn't be returned.

The length of preferences can vary.

Thank you very much.

Update:

What i tried is the following:

```
const query = realm.objects("Cars").filtered('specifications = preferences[0] OR specifications = preferences[1]')
```

As you see it is an OR operator which is surely wrong and it is hardcoded. Looping with realm really confuses me.

Comment: what code di you try ?

Comment: it is simple code, you make a loop (for for example) on your cars.specifications and check if every item is inside preferences

Comment: @AlainIb Thank for your response. I updated what i tried. But unfortunately it is an OR operator and the AND operator doesn't works. But the query is hardcoded as you see which is not fulfilling the requirement "length of preferences can vary". Looping with realm really confuses me. I believe you that it is simple code, but I went nuts and can't resolve it. Could please show how to loop it?

Comment: i dont use realm, i posted a js solution maybe it help

Answer (score 0):

This code will work!

```js
const collection = realm.objects('Cars');
const preferences = ["automatic","suv","blue","eco"];
let queryString = 'ANY ';
for (let i = 0; i < preferences.length; i++) {
         if (i === 0) {
              queryString += `specifications CONTAINS '${preferences[i]}'`;
            }
          if (i !== 0 && i + 1 <= preferences.length) {
                    queryString += ` OR specifications CONTAINS '${preferences[i]}'`;
          }
}
const matchedResult = collection.filtered(queryString);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

example of function to test if a word is inside an array of word

```
function inArray(word, array) {
  var lgth = array.length;
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < lgth; i++) { 
    array[i] = (array[i]).toLowerCase();
    if (array[i] == word) return true;
  }

  return false;
}

const preferences = ["automatic","suv","blue","eco"];

const specifications = ["automatic","suv"] ;
const specifications2 = ["automatic","suv", "boat"] ;

function test(spec,pref){ 
  for (var i in spec){
    if(!inArray(spec[i],pref)){
      return false ;
    }    
  }
  return true;   
}

console.log(test(specifications,preferences));
console.log(test(specifications2,preferences));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y1dz2gvu/

Comment: unfortunately thats not working. it must be a realm specific solution. I just read that realm doesnt supports queries on list properties. Just via a workaround